# How can I make a reliable and compact random timer?

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-legacy-console

I need to make a reliable random timer that powers a redstone wire and that is as small as possible. It should send about a pulse every second or half second, but obviously be slightly varied. It needs to never burn out (or fix itself when it burns out) and automatically turn on when the server starts up. I have tried to use a blink device, but I have found that those are very unreliable and are often predictable.

The reason I need to make this is so that a player cannot go up to a wire of mine that is flashing, figure out the flash pattern, and create their own timer that just links into the original and fools my original. If I had a randomly pulsing wire like the one I need, my circuit could detect when the redstone wire was messed with.

Comment: Couldn't they just break your wire and replace it with their own?  Computer security is not really an option in minecraft :)

Comment: No, I don't think so, because the way I have it set up they would need to add in a repeater, which would mess with the timing and send an alert. But, that's beside the point :)

Comment: How would your circuit detect when the wire was messed with?

Comment: There would be two wires, one hidden and one visible. The hidden one (or the visible one, it doesn't matter) is passed through a NOT gate so the two wires are opposites. The wires both flash randomly via this device I need. Repeaters are added to make sure the timing is exactly the same on both. Then, they are both passed through a hidden XNOR gate which could be connected to something like TNT. The XNOR by default outputs off, but if the wires are even out of sync a little bit it will output on, and could detonate the TNT and detect the change in its wiring.

Comment: I can think of a possible way to do something like this in Minecraft, but I don't own Minecraft for the Xbox 360. Does it have pistons? If so, this could definitely work...

Comment: Yes Jake, it has pistons.

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable redstone timer is this:

[image: yep, a chicken]

It seems pretty weird but chicken are the most reliable source of random! Let it wander in it's 2x1x2 cage and it will be definitely *random!*

Comment: I... don't think the console edition has command blocks (yet?). However this method could be salvaged by having the two pressure plates control two separate hopper clocks that run at different speeds. Wouldn't even take up much more room; make the command blocks any solid an place two sets of two hoppers feeding into each other on either side. In one set of hoppers, place a single item, in the other set two. Add a comparator to each hopper clock, and Bob's your uncle.